# how to create link that changes domain from localhost to actual domain name

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, localhost, anchor

I currently have a link in my html/css page that links to https://domain_name/route, which will take me to the actual website that is currently deployed on the internet. However, when I run the application locally, the link will change to localhost:7364/home, and since the link is hardcoded it will still link to the application that is running online. Is there a way to change this link so that it will change the appropriate link whether it's running locally or online (in AWS)? I know in node there is a property of the request object (headers.host) that I can pass into the html page, but ideally I'd like a solution that can just stick with html/css (and perhaps javascript) on the page.

The page runs via ejs so I'm wondering if there's a way to check within the page if it's running locally or online, and use an if statement to change the link? (without passing values into the page via node)

Answer (score 1):

you can check `window.location` and then change the href attribute.

Assuming your anchor is like this

```
<a href="aws.com/yourlink">The link</a>
```

Next in your code check where you are operating

```
if(window.location.host.indexOf('aws.com') {
  //modify your link href 
}
```